# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

Tags: c

Now, this code is *not* mine. The code belongs to the Chowdren Clickteam Compiler.

Now. I've been trying to fix this but the developer has been very busy. Now, I don't know C but I know a lot on Python and since this File is not Python. I can't fix it correctly. I've been getting a syntax error.

```
(C:\Users\Scrubby\Desktop\Clickteam Fusion 2.5 Projects\Chowdren Exporter\anaconda-master\Chowdren\base\desktop\tinyfiledialogs.c(178) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
C:\Users\Scrubby\Desktop\Clickteam Fusion 2.5 Projects\Chowdren Exporter\anaconda-master\Chowdren\base\desktop\tinyfiledialogs.c(184) : error C2065: 'lOldSubLen' : undeclared identifier)
```

Now the compiler I'm using is so people will stop extracting my source code for my games. Now, here is the code. Any help will be GREAT.

Line 178 and 184 are the ones that are breaking.

```
int lOldSubLen = strlen ( aOldSubStr ) ;
p = pOccurence + lOldSubLen ;
```

^^^ Thoses are the ones that are breaking.

I posted the void thingy below with the two broken lines.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8W_QnKwKijNN1JPanB3NXg1MU0

OR

```
static void replaceSubStr ( char const * const aSource ,
                            char const * const aOldSubStr ,
                            char const * const aNewSubStr ,
                            char * const aoDestination )
{
    char const * pOccurence ;
    char const * p ;
    char const * lNewSubStr = "" ;

    if ( ! aSource )
    {
        * aoDestination = '\0' ;
        return ;
    }
    if ( ! aOldSubStr )
    {
        strcpy ( aoDestination , aSource ) ;
        return ;
    }
    if ( aNewSubStr )
    {
        lNewSubStr = aNewSubStr ; 
    }
    p = aSource ;
    int lOldSubLen = strlen ( aOldSubStr ) ;
    * aoDestination = '\0' ;
    while ( ( pOccurence = strstr ( p , aOldSubStr ) ) != NULL )
    {
        strncat ( aoDestination , p , pOccurence - p ) ;
        strcat ( aoDestination , lNewSubStr ) ;
        p = pOccurence + lOldSubLen ;
    }
    strcat ( aoDestination , p ) ;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the offending source lines in your question.

Comment: Its better when you include the code you are talking about in the questino itself. Links tend to stop working after a while and Stackoverflow but people with similar compilation errors might still find this question via Google in the future.

Comment: Which compiler/development environnment/developpement tool do you use ?

Comment: I added the code now and I'm using Visual C++ 2008

Comment: An 8 year old Microsoft compiler which only supports a C language standard from 27 years ago (C89) is probably not your best bet here.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are using an older version of Visual C which does not support C99. You need to use a more modern compiler, either a current/recent version of Visual C, or ideally gcc, clang, or any modern C99-compliant compiler.

Alternatively if you are for some unfortunate reason stuck with your old version of Visual C then you could fix all such variable definitions to make them C89-compliant (i.e. move them to the start of an enclosing block).

The specific problem you are seeing is that variables are declared in the middle of a code block, rather than at the start - this has been allowed since C99 (and earlier, as an extension in compilers such as gcc). Microsoft has only recently caught up (more or less) with C99.

To fix the specific function which you are having problems with:

```
static void replaceSubStr ( char const * const aSource ,
                            char const * const aOldSubStr ,
                            char const * const aNewSubStr ,
                            char * const aoDestination )
{
    char const * pOccurence ;
    char const * p ;
    char const * lNewSubStr = "" ;
    int lOldSubLen ;  // <<< move variable definition to here

    if ( ! aSource )
    {
        * aoDestination = '\0' ;
        return ;
    }
    if ( ! aOldSubStr )
    {
        strcpy ( aoDestination , aSource ) ;
        return ;
    }
    if ( aNewSubStr )
    {
        lNewSubStr = aNewSubStr ; 
    }
    p = aSource ;
    lOldSubLen = strlen ( aOldSubStr ) ;  // <<< fixed line, without variable definition
    * aoDestination = '\0' ;
    while ( ( pOccurence = strstr ( p , aOldSubStr ) ) != NULL )
    {
        strncat ( aoDestination , p , pOccurence - p ) ;
        strcat ( aoDestination , lNewSubStr ) ;
        p = pOccurence + lOldSubLen ;
    }
    strcat ( aoDestination , p ) ;
}
```