# error c2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'type'

Tags: c

I have been trying to debug this error for the past few hours with no avail.
When using the following batch file to build my program,

```
    REM Build process for text editor
@echo off
pushd build
cl /Zi /MDd /IC:\Users\Giovanni\dev_lib\SDL2-2.0.4\include /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared" ..\*.c /link /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup /SUBSYSTEM:console /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Giovanni\dev_lib\SDL2-2.0.4\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Giovanni\dev_lib\SDL2_image-2.0.1\lib\x64 SDL2.lib SDL2main.lib SDL2_image.lib /out:text_editor.exe
popd
```

I get the following error message in CMD:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.c
..\main.c(36) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
```

My entire class is here:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

#define BOOL u32
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1024
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 576

typedef Uint32 u32;
typedef Uint64 u64;
typedef Sint32 i32;
typedef Sint64 i64;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Text Editor",
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                        SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0);
    assert(win);

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, 0, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
    assert(renderer);

    SDL_Texture *screen = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, 
                                            SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888, 
                                            SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 
                                            SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    assert(screen);

    u32 *screen_pixels = (u32*) calloc(SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT, sizeOf(u32));
    assert(screen_pixels);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

}
```

(its only 40 lines long)

If you could pleas explain what I am doing wrong (I am new to C), that would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: `sizeof()` is a _C_ operator, while `sizeOf()` is probably a typo.  (-:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37874759/971127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message indicates that the error is on line 36.

```
..\main.c(36) : error C2143:
```

I believe this is line 36:

```
 u32 *screen_pixels = (u32*) calloc(SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT,sizeOf(u32));
```

Do you see any typos there?  Can you identify each variable and call made on that line??

> `sizeof` is not the same thing as `sizeOf`

Comment: One typo is probably that sizeof() should be spelled with o instead of O.

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist:  You're ruining the surprise of my hidden text.

Answer (score 0):

I am not running Windows, but this looks odd:

```
u32 *screen_pixels = (u32*) calloc(SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT, sizeOf(u32));
```

Have you tried `sizeof` without capital `O`?

Comment: Bah, cannot see others responses while answering, all the same answers comments :-)